# RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to reproduce the [three.js panaorama dualfisheye example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=panoram#webgl_panorama_dualfisheye) using Three.js r71.

I need to stick to r71 because eventually I will use this code on autodesk forge viewer which is based on Three.js r71.

I made some progress, but I am facing an error message in the browser javascript console saying: `RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0`

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

var isUserInteracting = false,
  onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
  lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
  lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
  phi = 0, theta = 0,
  distance = 500;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  var container, mesh;

  container = document.getElementById('container');

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 500, 60, 40 ).toNonIndexed();
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(500, 60, 40);
  // invert the geometry on the x-axis so that all of the faces point inward
  // geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );
  geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));
  // Remap UVs

  // var normals = geometry.attributes.normal.array;
  var normals = [];
  geometry.faces.forEach(element => {
    normals.push(element.normal)
  });
  var uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs
  // var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;

  for (var i = 0, l = normals.length / 3; i < l; i++) {

    var x = normals[i * 3 + 0];
    var y = normals[i * 3 + 1];
    var z = normals[i * 3 + 2];

    if (i < l / 2) {

      var correction = (x == 0 && z == 0) ? 1 : (Math.acos(y) / Math.sqrt(x * x + z * z)) * (2 / Math.PI);
      uvs[i * 2 + 0] = x * (404 / 1920) * correction + (447 / 1920);
      uvs[i * 2 + 1] = z * (404 / 1080) * correction + (582 / 1080);

    } else {

      var correction = (x == 0 && z == 0) ? 1 : (Math.acos(- y) / Math.sqrt(x * x + z * z)) * (2 / Math.PI);
      uvs[i * 2 + 0] = - x * (404 / 1920) * correction + (1460 / 1920);
      uvs[i * 2 + 1] = z * (404 / 1080) * correction + (582 / 1080);

    }

  }

  geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(-Math.PI / 2))
  // geometry.rotateZ( - Math.PI / 2 );

  //

  // var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'ricoh_theta_s.jpg' );
  var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader('https://preview.ibb.co/hZXYmz/ricoh_theta_s.jpg');
  this.texture = texture;
  texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
  material.map.repeat = { x: 0, y: 0 }
  material.map.offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
  document.addEventListener('wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  isUserInteracting = true;

  onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
  onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

  onPointerDownLon = lon;
  onPointerDownLat = lat;

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  if (isUserInteracting === true) {

    lon = (onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
    lat = (onPointerDownPointerY - event.clientY) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

  }

}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {

  isUserInteracting = false;

}

function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {

  distance += event.deltaY * 0.05;

  distance = THREE.Math.clamp(distance, 400, 1000);

}

function animate() {

  // requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  update();

}

function update() {

  if (isUserInteracting === false) {

    lon += 0.1;

  }

  lat = Math.max(- 85, Math.min(85, lat));
  phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lat);
  theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(lon - 180);

  camera.position.x = distance * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
  camera.position.y = distance * Math.cos(phi);
  camera.position.z = distance * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/71/three.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues with the code

1. The loading code is wrong for r71. It should be something like this

   ```
   THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
   var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://preview.ibb.co/hZXYmz/ricoh_theta_s.jpg');
   ```
2. IIRC THREE r71 didn't pre-init textures with something renderable so you need to wait for the texture to load

   ```
   var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
      'https://preview.ibb.co/hZXYmz/ricoh_theta_s.jpg', 
       undefined,
       animate);  // call animate after texture has loaded
   ```

   and removed the call to `animate` at the top

That will get rid of the warning but continuing on

3. The code sets the repeat to 0

   ```
   material.map.repeat = { x: 0, y: 0 };
   material.map.offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
   ```

   Setting the repeat to 0 means you'll only see the first pixel of the texture since all UVs will be multiplied by 0
4. It code sets the repeat and offset incorrectly.

   The correct way to set repeat and offset is with set

   ```
   material.map.repeat.set(1, 1);
   material.map.offset.set(0, 0);
   ```

   It works the other way but only by luck. The 2 settings are `THREE.Vector2`
   objects. The code using repeat and offset could change at any time to 
   use methods on `THREE.Vector2` or pass the repeat and offset to functions
   that expect a `THREE.Vector2` so it's best not to replace them

   note that there is no reason to set them though. 1 1 for repeat and 0 0 for offset are the defaults.
5. The code only renders once

   `requestAnimationFrame` was commented out. Textures load asynchronously
   so you won't see the texture for several frames. You either need to wait
   for the texture to load before rendering, render again once it has finish
   loading or, render continuously so that when it happens to load it's used
6. The code is using a cross domain image

   This isn't actually a bug, just a warning. WebGL can't use cross domain
   images unless the server itself gives permission. The one the code links
   to does give that permission but I wasn't sure if you're aware of that
   or were just lucky. The majority of images from servers not your own
   are unlikely to work.
7. The code's uv math is wrong

   You should ask another question for that. Commenting that out I can see the texture

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

var isUserInteracting = false,
  onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
  lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
  lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
  phi = 0, theta = 0,
  distance = 500;

init();

function init() {

  var container, mesh;

  container = document.getElementById('container');

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  // var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 500, 60, 40 ).toNonIndexed();
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(500, 60, 40);
  // invert the geometry on the x-axis so that all of the faces point inward
  // geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );
  geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));
  // Remap UVs

  // var normals = geometry.attributes.normal.array;
  var normals = [];
  geometry.faces.forEach(element => {
    normals.push(element.normal)
  });
  var uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs
  // var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;

  for (var i = 0, l = normals.length / 3; i < l; i++) {

    var x = normals[i * 3 + 0];
    var y = normals[i * 3 + 1];
    var z = normals[i * 3 + 2];

    if (i < l / 2) {

      var correction = (x == 0 && z == 0) ? 1 : (Math.acos(y) / Math.sqrt(x * x + z * z)) * (2 / Math.PI);
     // uvs[i * 2 + 0] = x * (404 / 1920) * correction + (447 / 1920);
     // uvs[i * 2 + 1] = z * (404 / 1080) * correction + (582 / 1080);

    } else {

      var correction = (x == 0 && z == 0) ? 1 : (Math.acos(- y) / Math.sqrt(x * x + z * z)) * (2 / Math.PI);
     // uvs[i * 2 + 0] = - x * (404 / 1920) * correction + (1460 / 1920);
     // uvs[i * 2 + 1] = z * (404 / 1080) * correction + (582 / 1080);

    }

  }

  geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(-Math.PI / 2))
  // geometry.rotateZ( - Math.PI / 2 );

  //

  THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
  var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://preview.ibb.co/hZXYmz/ricoh_theta_s.jpg', undefined, animate);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
  material.map.repeat.set(1, 1);
  material.map.offset.set(0, 0);

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
  document.addEventListener('wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  isUserInteracting = true;

  onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
  onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

  onPointerDownLon = lon;
  onPointerDownLat = lat;

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  if (isUserInteracting === true) {

    lon = (onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
    lat = (onPointerDownPointerY - event.clientY) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

  }

}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {

  isUserInteracting = false;

}

function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {

  distance += event.deltaY * 0.05;

  distance = THREE.Math.clamp(distance, 400, 1000);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  update();

}

function update() {

  if (isUserInteracting === false) {

    lon += 0.1;

  }

  lat = Math.max(- 85, Math.min(85, lat));
  phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lat);
  theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(lon - 180);

  camera.position.x = distance * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
  camera.position.y = distance * Math.cos(phi);
  camera.position.z = distance * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/71/three.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I appreciated both the solution and the explanations you gave along the way. I will post a new question to ask for help with the UV mapping part.

Comment: Here is link to the follow-up UV mapping question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626174/how-do-i-figure-out-the-uv-mapping-from-ricoh-theta-s-dual-fish-eye-to-a-three-j

Comment: one minor change to fix the warning :P

Answer (score 0):

For those just looking for an answer to the warning
`RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0`

It is issued by Chrome when:

1. The bound shader program expects a texture.
2. No texture is bound.

Source and further links:
https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WebWorldWind/issues/302#issuecomment-346188472

The fix then, is to always bind a texture to the shader samplers, even when the shader won't use it.

As gman suggested in his longer answer, **binding a white 1px texture when "there is no texture" is good practice** because it won't consume much space or bandwidth and the shader code can use it to multiply with another colour without altering it.